# Выбивает ошибку при обращении к переменной класса

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, доступ

Задание состоит в создании класса трапеции с координатами точек в виде "х" и "у". Создал класс "Point" который имеет 2 переменные х и у.
При обращении к ним возникает ошибка "член Trapezoid::A недоступен"

```
    class Point {
public:
    int x, y;
};

class Trapezoid {


    Point A = Point();
    Point B = Point();
    Point C = Point();
    Point D = Point();
    Point H = Point();

    double GetAB() {
        return sqrt(pow(B.x - A.x, 2) + pow(B.y - A.y, 2));
    }

    double GetBC() {
        return sqrt(pow(C.x - B.x, 2) + pow(C.y - B.y, 2));
    }

    double GetCD() {
        return sqrt(pow(D.x - C.x, 2) + pow(D.y - C.y, 2));
    }

    double GetDA() {
        return sqrt(pow(A.x - D.x, 2) + pow(A.y - D.y, 2));
    }

    double Area() {
        return GetAB() * GetBC();
    }

    double Perimetr() {
        return (GetAB() + GetBC()) * 2;
    }


};

    int main()
{

    Trapezoid trapezoid = Trapezoid();
    trapezoid.A.x = 1;

}
```

Comment: `Point A = Point();` а мы точно на С++ пишем а не на Java?) В общем напишите просто `Point A`

Comment: Я прост с шарпа начинал вот и такое вот))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Данные члены класса `Trapezoid`

```
class Trapezoid {


    Point A = Point();
    Point B = Point();
    Point C = Point();
    Point D = Point();
    Point H = Point();
    // ...
```

являются закрытыми (то есть для класса (`class`) имеют по умолчанию управление доступом `private`). Поэтому данное обращение в `main` к закрытому члену класса `A`

```
trapezoid.A.x = 1;
```

не корректное.

Вы могли бы объявить отдельный метол, устанавливающий точки трапеции. Например,

```
void setABCD( Point a, Point b, Point c, Point d );
```

Обратите внимание, что вместо инициализации членов класса в виде

```
Point A = Point();
Point B = Point();
Point C = Point();
Point D = Point();
Point H = Point();
```

можно было бы написать

```
Point A = {};
Point B = {};
Point C = {};
Point D = {};
Point H = {};
```

И все ваши методы следует объявить с квалификатором const. Например,

```
double GetAB() const;
```

Answer (score 3):

`public` вы не написали? Тогда вы не можете использовать члены (которые в классе, в отличие от структуры, по умолчанию `private`) где-то, кроме как в самом классе...

И еще

```
Point A = Point();
```

это просто лишнее. Все эти `A` и иже с ними и так будут инициализированы конструктором по умолчанию.